# Can't update to webpack v3 via npm

Tags: npm, webpack

When I update webpack globally to latest version via npm's command:

```
npm update webpack@latest -g
```

i get installed v2.7.0 instead of the newest version for today which is v3.5.4.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with below commands,

To install webpack node module globally,

```
$ sudo npm i -g  webpack@3.5.4
```

or to install in your current directory under the node_module,

```
$ sudo npm i webpack@3.5.4
```